# destroy method does not appear to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.3 going through the Agile Rails dev book from PragProg

This destroy method on my ProductsController does not delete my product and I don't understand why.

Here is my first cut that I expected to 'just work'

```
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(products_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

But my test to assert the Product.count went down failed.

If I change to use the delete class method like this:

```
  def destroy
    Product.delete(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(products_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

my test passes.

Here is the test

```
  test "should destroy product" do
    assert_difference('Product.count', -1) do
      if @product.referenced_by_line_item
        @product.line_items.remove_all
      end
      delete :destroy, :id => @product.to_param
    end

    assert_redirected_to products_path
  end
```

I have a before_destroy method on my Product model class

```
  def referenced_by_line_item
    if line_items.count.zero?
      return true
    else
      errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
      return false
    end
  end
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? From reading the docs (and searching other questions here) I expect @product.destroy and Product.delete(id) to do the same thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling referenced_by_line_item before you do anything. If there are line items, it's returning false, so then you don't delete the line items. I don't think that's the behavior you want. If you changed it to:

```
  if !@product.referenced_by_line_item
    @product.line_items.remove_all
  end
  delete :destroy, :id => @product.to_param
```

then `@product.destroy` would probably work.

Although it would probably make more sense to reverse the logic in `referenced_by_line_item`. It would make more sense to say, if there are line items associated with this product, then this product is referenced by a line item. I think your logic is backwards.

Also, boolean methods should end with a '?'

I see the complication here though. You want it to return false when there are line items so that it doesn't save, but the return value is inconsistent with the method name. Maybe something like this would be better:

```
def no_line_items_present?
  if line_items.count > 0
    # add errors
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end
```

Then you can say:

```
  @product.line_items.remove_all unless @product.no_line_items_present?
  delete :destroy, :id => @product.to_param
```

Although I don't see the point in checking for line items before deciding to remove them except for a small performance increase.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain! My main goal here is to learn RoR not to have high perf code :)

Answer (score 3):

`delete` and `destroy` have a major difference - delete just deletes the row, without calling callbacks, as described in http://www.nickpeters.net/2007/12/21/delete-vs-destroy/

This being the case, using the delete bypasses your before_destroy method, which when run is adding errors to the object.  When you use delete, it ignores the errors, and thus changes the count.